# Printing a double instead of an integer in C

Tags: c, double

This code only works when I insert "%d" into the final printf. I guess that's because "ma" is an integer, but I want it to be a double, and I have declared it as such. How can I solve that?

"v" is already defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 25

double arithmeticMean(int v[N])
{
    double ma;
    int i,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        sum=sum+v[i];
    }
    ma=sum/N;
    return ma;
 }

int main()
{
    m1=arithmeticMean(v);
    printf("Arithmetic mean: %lf\n",m1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not defined `m1` or `v`.

Comment: This code does not include a declaration of `m1` nor of `v`, and won't compile.  Please read and follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  (I think I know what your problem is, but without seeing the declaration of `m1` I can't be sure.)

Comment: `ma=suma/N;` --> `ma=(double)sum/N;`

Comment: "I guess that's because `ma` is an integer". No. Firstly, `ma` is not an integer. Secondly, `ma` does not participate in the final `printf`.

Comment: You mention `double`. The format specifier `%lf` is correct for `scanf` but not for `printf` where it should be simply `%f`. So what happens to `float`? It gets promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`.

Comment: Beware that `sum/N` is integer math as-is and won't probably do what you expect.

Comment: m1 was declared as an integer, silly of me, thanks

Comment: Your mean function still will be truncated as written.  Beware.

Comment: And what of `v`? Please update the question.

Comment: `v` is a vector of integers, the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Because `printf` takes a variable number of arguments, the compiler does not know what type the arguments after the format string are "meant" to be.  When you write

```
int m1 = arithmeticMean(v);
printf("Arithmetic mean: %lf\n", m1);
```

the compiler passes `m1` to `printf` *as an `int`*.  But the `%lf` "format effector" is expecting a `double`, which is almost always not the same size as `int`, and may be stored a different place altogether -- so you get nonsense output. (Technically, this code has "undefined behavior" and might crash or even make demons fly out of your nose, but nonsense output is far more likely.)  (Also, `%lf` is wrong in and of itself, because the `l` modifier is not allowed to be used with `f`, but most C libraries in my experience will just act like you wrote `%f`.)

If you really want to force `printf` to print an `int` variable as though it were floating-point you must write an explicit cast:

```
printf("Arithmetic mean: %f\n", (double)m1);
```

or fake it in the format string:

```
printf("Arithmetic mean: %d.0\n", m1);
```

However, for the program you appear to be trying to write, the correct change is to declare `m1` as a `double`, not an `int`, consistent with the return value of `arithmeticMean`.  The mean of a set of integers is not necessarily an integer.

(When might you genuinely want to force `printf` to print an integer in floating-point notation?  Perhaps when it is very large:

```
printf("%.1e\n", (double)(1000l * 1000 * 1000));
```

would print `1.0e9`, which is easier for a human to understand than `1000000000`.)